# The inverse mellin transform of the reciprocal of the Archimedean factor of the Zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, number-theory, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

How to compute the inverse Mellin transform of $\frac{1}{\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)}$? Or equivalently, if $*$ denote the multiplicative convolution, what is the convolutional inverse of $e^{-x^2\pi}$? that is, $f$ such that

$$e^{-x^2\pi}*f=\delta(t-1).$$

Thank you.

Comment: This grows exponentially along vertical lines and so does not have an inverse Mellin transform.

Comment: You just defined it: if $\mathcal{M}(f)$ decays fast enough on vertical lines then the inverse of $f\mapsto  f \ast e^{-\pi x^2}$ is $f\mapsto \mathcal{M}^{-1}(\mathcal{M}(f)\pi^{-s/2}/\Gamma(s/2))$. This is the concept of analytic functionals, looking at convolution operators on smaller classes than Schwartz functions.